# Selecting newly added dom elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dynamic

So in vanilla JS I made a class with a function that is suppose to add elements to the document but after those elements are added I also wanted to add a function that will remove selected elements. My problem is that when I try to query select the newly added elements it returns an empty array or node. can anyone give me a reason why and how to fix? Another side not if I got to the developer console I can select the new elements without a problem

```
class Stock_List {
  constructor() {
    // fetching the json file and building
    this.getData();
  }

  /**
   * this will read the json file, get the data needed
   * and then build up the initial list on startup that was
   * saved in the json file
   */
  async getData() {
    const response = await fetch('../stocks.json');
    const data = await response.json();
    for (const stock of data.stock_info) {
      this.add_stock(stock);
    }
  }

  /**
   * this will add a stock to the front end
   * @param {*} jsObject - A JavaScript Object of stock info
   */
  add_stock(jsObject) {
    let big_container = document.querySelector('.background');
    // this statement fixes the background once a stock is added
    big_container.style.position = 'sticky';
    let stock_container = document.createElement('div');
    stock_container.className = 'stock_container';
    stock_container.id = jsObject['stock_ticker'];
    // stock header being built
    stock_container.innerHTML = `
    <div class="stock_header">
      <h2 class="stock_ticker">${jsObject['stock_ticker']}</h2>
      <h2 class="price">${jsObject['price']}</h2>
      <h2 class="percent_change">${jsObject['percent_change']}</h2>
      <button>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </button>
    </div>`;
    // articles being built
    for (let i = 0; i < jsObject['headers'].length; i++) {
      stock_container.innerHTML += `
      <div class="articles">
        <h3>${jsObject['headers'][i]}</h3>
        <p>
          ${jsObject['articles'][i]}
        </p>`;
    }
    //closing off the div of the stock container
    stock_container.innerHTML += `
    </div>`;

    big_container.appendChild(stock_container);
  }

  /*
  removes a stock from the front end
  and calls a function to remove it from the back end
  */
  remove_stock(ticker) {
    let removed_stock = document.querySelector(`#${ticker}`);
    console.log(removed_stock);
  }
}
```

Comment: How and when you are calling `remove_stock` and what you are passing as `ticker`?

Comment: @HarshSaini I call remove_stock after the object is created and ticker is a string passed into it looking for an id of the newly created dom element

Comment: all i was doing in this sample code was trying to select one of the newly created dom elements after the object was created. But I was getting an empty return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this using event delegation. You need to add an event listener to the parent (in your case, `big_container`).

```js
big_container.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Guard clause
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('classname-of-the-ticker')) return;
  clickedItem = e.target;
  clickedItem.remove();
})
```